# Sending multiple emails with different body using Laravel8

Tags: laravel, email

I have the following data :

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => "email1@gmail.com"
    1 => "email2@gmail.com"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    0 => "email3@gmail.com"
  ]
]
```

And  have the following data in my database :

```
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id_filiale     |  adm_emails                                               |     
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|1               |  ["email1@gmail.com","email2@gmail.com"]                  |  
|2               |  ["email3@gmail.com"]                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I want to foreach emails send a specific data ,so I'm tryin the following code  :

```
Mail::send([], [],
  function ($m){
    $today_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(60);
    foreach ($emails as $key3 => $value) {
       $filiale = Filiale::where('adm_email', json_encode($value))
            ->select('filiales.id_filiale')
            ->value('filiales.id_filiale');  
      
       $contras = Projet_Casting::join('contrats','contrats.id_contrat','=','projets_castings.id_contrat')
            ->leftjoin('projets','projets.id_projet','=','projets_castings.id_projet')
            ->join('castings','castings.id_casting','=','contrats.id_casting')
            ->where('contrats.actif',1)
            ->where('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '<=', $today_date)
            ->where('projets.id_filiale',$filiale)
            ->get();

  /* dd($contras);*/ 

       foreach($value as $val =>$v){
          $m->to($v,'Notify')->subject('Contrats à renouveler')->setBody($contras);
       }
    }  
 });
```

But it sends to all emails the same data and only the last record in the table `Projet_Casting`.

What is wrong with my code ? if you have any idea about how I can send specific data to specific email according to a condition , please help.

Thank you in advance !

**UPDATE**

I'm trying that :

```
 $today_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(60);
                    $contrat_email = Projet_Casting::join('contrats','contrats.id_contrat','=','projets_castings.id_contrat')->leftjoin('projets','projets.id_projet','=','projets_castings.id_projet')->join('castings','castings.id_casting','=','contrats.id_casting')->join('filiales','projets.id_filiale','=','filiales.id_filiale')->where('contrats.actif',1)->where('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '<=', $today_date)->distinct('filiales.id_filiale')->get();
                  $emails = array();
                 foreach($contrat_email as $key) {
                   $emails[] = json_decode($key->adm_email);
                   
                  }
                   $email_send = array();
                    foreach ($emails as $key3 => $value) {
                       $filiale =Filiale::where('adm_email', json_encode($value))->select('filiales.id_filiale')->value('filiales.id_filiale');
                
                      $contras = Projet_Casting::join('contrats','contrats.id_contrat','=','projets_castings.id_contrat')->leftjoin('projets','projets.id_projet','=','projets_castings.id_projet')->join('castings','castings.id_casting','=','contrats.id_casting')->where('contrats.actif',1)->where('contrats.date_fin_contrat', '<=', $today_date)->where('projets.id_filiale',$filiale)->get();
                     /* dd($contras);*/ 
                     
                     foreach($value as $val =>$v){          
                        $ema = $v;
                      }
                       Mail::send([],[],
                       function ($m){
                      $m->to($ema,'Notify')->subject('Contrats à renouveler')->setBody($contras);
                      }); 
                     }
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
"Undefined variable: ema"
```

Comment: I assume you need to foreach Mail::send instead, not as a part of a Closure.

Comment: How ? please explain more

Comment: You use function Mail::send() once, as far as I can see, and then foreach data inside. 
As you need different emails and different data to be sent, just fetch the data first and then foreach it as you do now. After you receive email and necessary data, Call Mail::send() (many times);

Comment: @MaxShaian , please check my updated question

Comment: I would try to use a different syntax according to the documentation
Mail::to()->send(content)

Comment: okey , thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237785/discussion-between-saadia-and-max-shaian).